# Any Way To Get TypeScript To Not Error When Not Using One Parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have a method call as follows where I'm not using the `res` parameter but am using the `next` parameter.  I don't want to use `// @ts-ignore` but not sure what the best practice is to handle this situation.

Thoughts?

```
server.post('/rpc/Account/IsLoggedIn', function(req: any, res: any, next: () => {}) {
    req.body = 'abcd'
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an underscore _ to the params that you don't wanna use. By doing this, TypeScript won't complain about the unused variables.

```
server.post('/rpc/Account/IsLoggedIn', function(_req: any, _res: any, next: () => {}) {
    req.body = 'abcd'
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `undefined` as second argument, at position of `res` argument, to the function while making the function call. Not sure if its best practice but that will work.

For example:

```
fn(arg1, undefined, arg2);
```

Make sure to check the value is not `undefined` in cases where you require the value of `res` inside the function and handle cases accordingly.